# Populating Core Data with Plist in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

Working on an application that I want to check the plist store that the app will come shipped with and prepopulate core data with the objects from the plist. I think....I am looking for advice on this part of my application. As this is my first time coding and I have been learning Core Data/Persistence more recently I am not used to reading C++ or any of the code completely prior to Swift. I understand it somewhat but not enough to actually know the order of coding within swift.

That being said I created a plist file that contains an array of objects that each of those objects contains either strings or integers depending on the value that was necessary. Now in those objects I actually made a "serial" number as it were so that I could refer to specific objects easily or use it as a means to store that particular string and save only that so that it could be recalled from the plist. I have no idea whether I should actually upload all the objects to core data or just leave them in plist. Nor do I have any idea which way to begin this section of code.

From my basic understanding of plist and the fact that I saved the serial as a string I figured I could present the objects selected by storing the string alone to the core data model then have the core data model recall all objects from the plist that contain that serial and present it to the user. Basically any small sample coding in swift that can actually head me in the right direction would be a big help! Also is it faster to do it this way or would it be faster/better to upload the objects to core data on the first launch/updated lists? How would I go about this method if that was better? I spent the better half of the last few days trying to read through non swift code and haven't progressed enough I feel.

Sorry if this is n00bish I am self taught in swift and really trying to learn the best ways for all this as I have a lot of ideas that I wish to personally create/oversee!

Comment: You should check out Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1). It was updated this year and includes Swift code examples.

Comment: Code examples not being the only important part of the question though...I was wondering if it actually matters which way I actually do this...If i leave it as a plist and just call the serializations or if I actually import the whole plist into core data. I wondered if there is a difference in both performance and in the ability to prevent future errors/bugs.